# Error en actualizar y borrar usuarios - JSP y Servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

Cuando me excedo de 10 caracteres a la hora de cambiar la contraseña de usuario, me sale este error:

[image: Respuesta del error]

Y cuando quiero eliminar me sale este error:

[image: Error 500 al querer eliminar]

CODIGO DE ActualizarUsuarios.jsp:

```
<%@page import="pe.edu.sise.bean.ErrorBean"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Actualizar Usuarios</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            if (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("IDUSUARIO"))!=0 &&
                    request.getParameter("USUARIO") != null
                    && request.getParameter("PASSWORD") != null) 
            {
                session.setAttribute("IDUSUARIO", Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("IDUSUARIO")));
        %>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="ActualizarUsuarioServlet" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h2>Actualizar Usuarios</h2>
                    <jsp:useBean id="error" scope="request" class="pe.edu.sise.bean.ErrorBean"/>
                    <%--igual 
               <%
                   ErrorBean error = new ErrorBean();
               %> --%>
                    <label>IDUSUARIO</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtIdusuario" readonly="readonly" value="<%=request.getParameter("IDUSUARIO")%>" class="form-control">
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>USUARIO</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtUsuario" value="<%=request.getParameter("USUARIO")%>" class="form-control">
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtPassword" value="<%=request.getParameter("PASSWORD")%>" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Modificación</button>
                    <%
                        if (error.getMsg() != null){
                    %>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <jsp:getProperty name="error" property="msg" /> 
                        <%-- <%= error.getMsg()%> --%>
                    </div>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                </div>
            </form>
            <% } %>
            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/usuarios.jsp">Atrás</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CODIGO DE EliminarUsuarios.jsp:

```
<%@page import="pe.edu.sise.bean.ErrorBean"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
        <title>Eliminar Usuarios</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            if(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID"))!=0 &&
                    request.getParameter("USUARIO")!=null &&
                request.getParameter("PASSWORD")!=null)
            {
                session.setAttribute("IDUSUARIO", Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("IDUSUARIO")));
        %>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="EliminarUsuarioServlet" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
               <h2>Eliminar Usuarios</h2>
               <jsp:useBean id="error" scope="request" class="pe.edu.sise.bean.ErrorBean" />
               <%--igual 
               <%
                   ErrorBean error = new ErrorBean();
               %> --%>
               <label>IdUsuario</label>
               <input type="hidden" name="txtIdusuario"  value="<%=request.getParameter("IDUSUARIO")%>" class="form-control">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
               <label>Usuario</label>
               <input type="text" name="txtUsuario"  value="<%=request.getParameter("USUARIO")%>" class="form-control">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
               <label>Password</label>
               <input type="text" name="txtPassword" value="<%=request.getParameter("PASSWORD")%>" class="form-control">
               </div>

               <div class="form-group text-center">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Confirmar Eliminación de Usuario</button>
               <%
                   if (error.getMsg() != null) {
               %>
               <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <jsp:getProperty name="error" property="msg" /> 
                   <%-- <%= error.getMsg()%> --%>
               </div>
               <%
                   }
               %>
               </div>
            </form>
        <% } %>
        <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/usuarios.jsp">Atrás</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CODIGO DE usuarios.jsp:

```
<%@page import="pe.edu.sise.bean.Usuarios"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="pe.edu.sise.dao.ConexionBD"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <title>Mantenimiento Usuarios</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <h2>Usuarios:</h2>
            <tr>
                <th>IdUsuario</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Password (Contraseña)</th>
            </tr>
            <%
                ConexionBD conexionBD = new ConexionBD();
                List<Usuarios> lista = conexionBD.listarUsuarios();
                for (Usuarios u : lista) {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= u.getIDUSUARIO()%></td>
                <td><%= u.getUSUARIO()%></td>
                <td><%= u.getPASSWORD()%></td>
                <td><a href="ActualizarUsuarios.jsp?IDUSUARIO=<%= u.getIDUSUARIO()%>&&USUARIO=<%= u.getUSUARIO()%>&&PASSWORD=<%= u.getPASSWORD()%>">Actualizar</a></td>
                <td><a href="EliminarUsuarios.jsp?IDUSUARIO=<%= u.getIDUSUARIO()%>&&USUARIO=<%= u.getUSUARIO()%>&&PASSWORD=<%= u.getPASSWORD()%>">Eliminar</a></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </table>
    <center><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/menu.jsp">Ir al menú</a></center>
</body>
</html>
```

CODIGO DE ActualizarUsuarioServlet.java:

```
package pe.edu.sise.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import pe.edu.sise.bean.ErrorBean;
import pe.edu.sise.bean.Usuarios;
import pe.edu.sise.dao.ConexionBD;

public class ActualizarUsuarioServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);
        ConexionBD conexionBD = new ConexionBD();
        Usuarios usuarios = new Usuarios();


        String nombreUsuario = request.getParameter("txtUsuario");
        String password = request.getParameter("txtPassword");
        int idusuario =  Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtIdusuario"));

        usuarios.setUSUARIO(nombreUsuario);
        usuarios.setPASSWORD(password);
        usuarios.setIDUSUARIO(idusuario);

        int resultado = conexionBD.ActualizarUsuarios(usuarios);

        if (resultado == 1) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/usuarios.jsp");
        } else {
            //Página Error....
        }
    }

    public void gestionaError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, int code,
            String msg) throws Exception {
        ErrorBean error = new ErrorBean();
        error.setCode(1);
        error.setMsg("No se pudo actualizar la información");

        request.setAttribute("error", error);

        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher rd = ctx.getRequestDispatcher("/ActualizarUsuarios.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

CODIGO DE EliminarUsuarioServlet.java:

```
package pe.edu.sise.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import pe.edu.sise.bean.ErrorBean;
import pe.edu.sise.bean.Usuarios;
import pe.edu.sise.dao.ConexionBD;

/**
 *
 * @author FAMARESAM-PC
 */
public class EliminarUsuarioServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);
        ConexionBD conexionBD =  new ConexionBD();
        Usuarios usuarios =  new Usuarios();

        int idusu=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtIdusuario"));

        usuarios.setIDUSUARIO(idusu);

        int resultado = conexionBD.EliminarUsuarios(usuarios);

        if(resultado == 1){
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/usuarios.jsp");
        }else{

        }
    }
     public void gestionaError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, int code,
            String msg) throws Exception {
        ErrorBean error = new ErrorBean();
        error.setCode(1);
        error.setMsg("No se pudo registrar la información");

        request.setAttribute("error", error);

        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher rd = ctx.getRequestDispatcher("/EliminarUsuarios.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

CODIGO DE ConexionBD.java:

```
package pe.edu.sise.dao;

// Paso 2: Importar el paquete sql
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import pe.edu.sise.bean.Producto;
import pe.edu.sise.bean.Usuarios;


public class ConexionBD {

    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public ConexionBD() {
        try {
            //Paso 1: Registrar el Driver de Conexión de SQL Server
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public boolean loginUsuario(String usuario, String contrasenia) {
        boolean usuarioValido = false;
        //Paso 3: Conectarse a la Base de Datos
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\.:1433;databaseName=sisebd;user=sa;password=123");
            //Paso 4: ejecuto mi Consulta/Query
            String sql = "SELECT USUARIO, PASSWORD FROM TBL_USER WHERE USUARIO=? AND PASSWORD=?";

            PreparedStatement prst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            prst.setString(1, usuario.trim());
            prst.setString(2, contrasenia.trim());
            rs = prst.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                usuarioValido = true;
            }
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return usuarioValido;
    }

    public List<Producto> listarProductos() {
        List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\.:1433;databaseName=sisebd;user=sa;password=123");
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_PRODUCTO";
            Statement cmd = con.createStatement();
            rs = cmd.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                Producto p = new Producto();
                p.setID(rs.getInt(1));
                p.setNOMBRE(rs.getString(2));
                p.setCANTIDAD(rs.getInt(3));
                p.setPRECIO_UNIT(rs.getDouble(4));
                productos.add(p);
            }
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return productos;
    }

    public int InsertarProducto(Producto objp) {
        int resultado = 0;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\.:1433;databaseName=sisebd;user=sa;password=123");
            String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_producto(NOMBRE,CANTIDAD,PRECIO_UNIT) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, objp.getNOMBRE());
            ps.setInt(2, objp.getCANTIDAD());
            ps.setDouble(3, objp.getPRECIO_UNIT());
            resultado = ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {

        }
        return resultado;
    }

    public int ActualizarProducto(Producto objp) {
        int res = 0;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\.:1433;databaseName=sisebd;user=sa;password=123");
            String sql = "UPDATE tbl_producto SET NOMBRE=?,CANTIDAD=?,PRECIO_UNIT=? WHERE ID=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, objp.getNOMBRE());
            ps.setInt(2, objp.getCANTIDAD());
            ps.setDouble(3, objp.getPRECIO_UNIT());
            ps.setInt(4, objp.getID());

            res = ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {

        }
        return res;

    }

    public int EliminarProducto(Producto objp) {
        int res = 0;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\.:1433;databaseName=sisebd;user=sa;password=123");
            String sql = "DELETE FROM TBL_PRODUCTO WHERE ID=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, objp.getID());

            res = ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {

        }
        return res;

    }

    public List<Usuarios> listarUsuarios() {
        List<Usuarios> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\.:1433;databaseName=sisebd;user=sa;password=123");
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_USER";
            Statement cmd = con.createStatement();
            rs = cmd.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                Usuarios u = new Usuarios();
                u.setIDUSUARIO(rs.getInt(1));
                u.setUSUARIO(rs.getString(2));
                u.setPASSWORD(rs.getString(3));
                usuarios.add(u);
            }
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return usuarios;
    }

    public int InsertarUsuarios(Usuarios obju) {
        int res = 0;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\.:1433;databaseName=sisebd;user=sa;password=123");
            String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(USUARIO, PASSWORD) VALUES(?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, obju.getUSUARIO());
            ps.setString(2, obju.getPASSWORD());
            res = ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {

        }
        return res;
    }

    public int ActualizarUsuarios(Usuarios obju) {
        int res = 0;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\.:1433;databaseName=sisebd;user=sa;password=123");
            String sql = "UPDATE TBL_USER SET USUARIO=?,PASSWORD=? WHERE IDUSUARIO=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, obju.getUSUARIO());
            ps.setString(2, obju.getPASSWORD());     
            ps.setInt(3, obju.getIDUSUARIO());
            res = ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {

        }
        return res;
    }

    public int EliminarUsuarios(Usuarios obju) {
        int res = 0;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\.:1433;databaseName=sisebd;user=sa;password=123");
            String sql = "DELETE FROM TBL_USER WHERE IDUSUARIO=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, obju.getIDUSUARIO());
            res = ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {

        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

CODIGO DE LA CLASE Usuarios.java:

```
package pe.edu.sise.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Usuarios implements Serializable{

    private int IDUSUARIO;
    private String USUARIO;
    private String PASSWORD;

    public int getIDUSUARIO() {
        return IDUSUARIO;
    }

    public void setIDUSUARIO(int IDUSUARIO) {
        this.IDUSUARIO = IDUSUARIO;
    }


    public String getUSUARIO() {
        return USUARIO;
    }

    public void setUSUARIO(String USUARIO) {
        this.USUARIO = USUARIO;
    }

    public String getPASSWORD() {
        return PASSWORD;
    }


    public void setPASSWORD(String PASSWORD) {
        this.PASSWORD = PASSWORD;
    }

}
```

CODIGO DE ErrorBean.java:

```
package pe.edu.sise.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ErrorBean implements Serializable{

    private String msg;
    private int code;

    /**
     * @return the msg
     */
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    /**
     * @param msg the msg to set
     */
    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    /**
     * @return the code
     */
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    /**
     * @param code the code to set
     */
    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

CÓDIGO DE LA BASE DE DATOS (SQL SERVER):

```
CREATE DATABASE sisebd
GO
USE sisebd
GO

CREATE TABLE TBL_USER(
IDUSUARIO INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
USUARIO VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PASSWORD VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TBL_USER VALUES ('admin','123');
INSERT INTO TBL_USER VALUES ('parellano', '123456');
INSERT INTO TBL_USER VALUES ('jmatos', 'agffd451');

SELECT * FROM TBL_USER;


CREATE TABLE TBL_PRODUCTO(
ID int identity (1,1) not null primary key,
NOMBRE varchar(50) not null,
CANTIDAD int not null,
PRECIO_UNIT decimal(18,2) not null
);

INSERT INTO TBL_PRODUCTO VALUES ('LECHE', 50, 2);
INSERT INTO TBL_PRODUCTO VALUES ('PESCADO', 300, 15);
INSERT INTO TBL_PRODUCTO VALUES ('ARROZ',200,3);
INSERT INTO TBL_PRODUCTO VALUES ('AZUCAR',250,2);

SELECT * FROM TBL_PRODUCTO;
```

Comment: Te asegurarse que: `<input type="hidden" name="txtIdusuario" value="<%=request.getParameter("IDUSUARIO")%>" class="form-control"/>` tenga un valor?

Comment: Mitsu Gami, sí tiene valor el IDUSUARIO, se generan los valores en la BD mediante un IDENTITY (1,1)

Comment: La excepción que te da te indica que en algún punto, has intentado convertir un string a número - asumo que el ID del usuario - pero en lugar de ello, ha recibido null. El problema es que no sabremos en dónde hasta que coloques el rastreo de pila. Colocalo para observar mejor el problema. PD: Anda aprendiendo a depurar.

Comment: Lo que yo quiero soluciones es sobre todo a la hora de eliminar usuarios, ahi es lo peor...

Comment: Por eso mismo, para que puedas dar una solución no todo es código, hay que tener encuentra otros factores. El rastreo de pila es el texto rojo que aparece en la consola de tu IDE y que brinda información sobre la causa y el contexto del problema. Actualiza tu pregunta y pega ese texto.

Comment: Encontraron alguna solución . Yo tambien tengo el mismo problema :(

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que dice la excepción la aplicación, en `EliminarUsuario` **esperaba un número y ha recibido un null**.

Supongo que tienes el error en cómo escribes las rutas y como las procesas. Por lo que veo las escribes así:

```
<td><a href="ActualizarUsuarios.jsp?IDUSUARIO=<%= u.getIDUSUARIO()%>&&USUARIO=<%= u.getUSUARIO()%>&&PASSWORD=<%= u.getPASSWORD()%>">Actualizar</a></td>
<td><a href="EliminarUsuarios.jsp?IDUSUARIO=<%= u.getIDUSUARIO()%>&&USUARIO=<%= u.getUSUARIO()%>&&PASSWORD=<%= u.getPASSWORD()%>">Eliminar</a></td>
```

Osea, que tanto a `ActualizarUsuarios.jsp` como a `EliminarUsuarios.jsp` le envías los parámetros mediante el método GET. Sin embargo en los servelts sobreescribes el método **doPost** en vez de **doGet**. Vamos que envías por GET y esperas recibir por POST.

Muy probablemente ese sea el error.

Comment: Asuu pero qué raro, si todo lo hice en los servlets con el método POST y en los formularios de JSP también, y el CRUD para aplicarlo en la tabla TBL_PRODUCTOS sí me funciona bien y encima lo hice del mismo modo... :( :(

Comment: Hola Ricardo, además ahi estoy llamando a las clases y a sus respectivos getters que están escritos en MAYÚSCULAS: `<td><a href="ActualizarUsuarios.jsp?IDUSUARIO=<%= u.getIDUSUARIO()%>&&USUARIO=<%= u.getUSUARIO()%>&&PASSWORD=<%= u.getPASSWORD()%>">Actualizar</a></td>
<td><a href="EliminarUsuarios.jsp?IDUSUARIO=<%= u.getIDUSUARIO()%>&&USUARIO=<%= u.getUSUARIO()%>&&PASSWORD=<%= u.getPASSWORD()%>">Eliminar</a></td> `

Comment: Por ejemplo en EliminarUsuarios.sjp pasas los parámetros por GET, esto es en la misma URL y en EliminarUsuarioServlet.java esperas recibirlos en POST ¿Te das cuenta?